# Преобразование кода Python в C

Tags: python, c

Как преобразовать следующий Python код в код на C?

```py
file = open('filename.txt')
n,k = file.read().split()
```

Answer (score 4):

Нечто вроде:

```
FILE *file;
char *n, *k, *blank;
char buf[255];

// Читаем строку
file = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
fgets(buf, 255, file);

// Первое слово отделяется пробелом)
blank = index(buf, ' ' );
*blank = '\0';
n = strdup(buf); 

// Всё оставшееся - второе слово
k = strdup(blank+1); 
while(*k == ' ') k++; // Убираем лидирующие пробелы
// Ещё надо убрать символы перевода строки в конце строки k
// Но это зависит от ОС: Windows/Linux, поэтому здесь не пишу.
```

Не тестировал, поэтому возможны опечатки.